# Error: timeout of 2000ms exceeded. Unit test with promises

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, mocha.js, assert

My unit tests make http requests to NET API and use kriskowal q library. When I do `assert` call in `then` callback and assertion fails I see `Error: timeout of 2000ms exceeded` instead of  `AssertionError`. I wrote example to illustrate this situation:

```
var assert = require('assert')
  , Q = require('q');

it('promise', function(cb){
    var deferred = Q.defer();
    deferred.promise.then(function(){
        assert(false);
        cb();
    });
    deferred.resolve();
});
```

I can't understand this behaviour.  Modelling asynchronous behaviour with `setTimeout/setImmediate` shows normal `AssertionError`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Q does not provide unhandled rejection tracking, you need to explicitly `.done` promises to signal a chain has ended. You get a suppressed error in your test:

```
it('promise', function(cb){
    var deferred = Q.defer();
    deferred.promise.then(function(){
        assert(false);
        cb();
    }).done(); // NOTE THE DONE
    deferred.resolve();
});
```

Mocha however, provides better promise syntax, you can simply return a promise and have the rejection turn to a test failure:

```
it('promise', function(cb){
    return new Q.Promise(function(resolve){ resolve(); }). // use the new syntax
    then(function(){
        assert(false);
        cb();
    });// no done needed because of the `return`
});
```

Comment: @user3414982 glad I could help, you might want to consider a better promise implementation.